# Get splunk version and update it with ansible if version is not meet

Tags: ansible, splunk

I'm new on stackoverflow and I'm very glad to be here.

My question is:

I want to get the Splunk version and then if version is not equal to e.g "8" or something else, then stop Splunk and uninstasll it and install the right version.

Here is my Ansible playbook I write to get the version.

```
  tasks:
  - name: Read splunk.version file
    slurp:
      src: C:\\Program Files\\SplunkUniversalForwarder\\etc\\splunk.version
    register: result
    ignore_errors: true

  - name: set splunk version
    set_fact:
      splunk_version: "{{ result['content'] | b64decode | regex_findall('(?<=VERSION\\=).*?(?=\\r)') }}"

  - name: message
    debug:
      var: splunk_version

  - name: message
    debug:
      msg: "same version installed"
    when: splunk_version == "8.0.3"
```

And here my result

```
TASK [Read splunk.version file] 
********************
ok: [192.168.*.*]

TASK [set splunk version]
*********************
ok: [192.168.*.*]

TASK [message] 
***********************
ok: [192.168.*.*] => {
    "splunk_version": [
        "8.0.3"
    ]
}

TASK [message] 
***********************
skipping: [192.168.*.*]
```

As you see despite being in same version, I get wrong result. I know I made a mistake in my comparison conditions but I don't know where!

So I'm very appreciative if anyone could correct my playbook.

Sorry for my mistakes

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

splunk_version is an array. Try splunk_version[0] == "8.0.3" instead.